# How can I set an Attribute as a Parameter in Acumatica Report Designer?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created an attribute for Stock Item screen, I want that attribute as a parameter in my report .rpx file. My attribute is of combo type attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small customization which shows how to add a specific attribute to the report parameter.
First create a custom DAC.  In my case, I chose to expose the INDUSTRY attribute.

```
 public class IndustryAttr : IBqlTable
 {
    #region UsrIndustry
    [PXDBString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Industry")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<CSAttributeDetail.valueID,      
    Where<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID,Equal<ind>>>),
    typeof(CSAttributeDetail.valueID),
    typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description))]
    public virtual string UsrIndustry { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrIndustry : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrIndustry>  {}
    #endregion
}

public class ind : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<ind>
{
    public ind()
      : base("INDUSTRY")
    {
    }
}
```

Next I added the parameter in the report.  Pay attention to the attribute declaration.
[image]

Now the Industry attribute appears as the selector

[image]